# App crashing in landscape orientation while displaying the loading screen

Tags: java, android, xml, landscape

I display an initial splash screen by creating a `Splash_Screen` class and setting my manifest like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Splash_Screen">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

my `Splash_Screen` class looks like this:

```
public class Splash_Screen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

I created a default layout file for the splash screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Splash_Screen">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_default"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and afterwards within the preview panel I created a second XML file by selecting the "orientation for Preview" drop-down menu and selected "create landscape version". In the new file, I exchanged the `ImageView` Source-File. My layout structure looks like this:

[image: layout folder]

Now, when the app displays the splash screen and I am in landscape mode (no matter if I started this way or if I change to it from portrait mode) the app crashes. Within the app it won't crash in landscape mode.

What did I miss?

Comment: Just remember, each time you rotate the screen activity is recreated. You must save your's activity state. I guess your app crashes on this line (startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));)??

Would be nice if we see the log.

Comment: This is not how you should create a loading screen... Even for the sake of branding it's a horrible approach. This is better https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Comment: @ZUNJAE I agree with you and I did it like described there. But how can I set different Imaged for different screen-sizes/orientations there?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

Comment: @ZUNJAE I can see how that article helps with different screen sizes so I can use images with different resolutions, but I got different images for the orientation as well and I can't see a hint for that in this article. Would it be better to block landscape mode during the loading screen (if this is even possible)?

Comment: I don't think it's good if I help you here because your approach for splash screens is bad.

Comment: As I said I restructured and used the method you described